# Vuetify locale doesn't work in datepicker header

Tags: datepicker, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify datepicker with a French locale. Although everything is fine in the calendar, the "selected" translation doesn't apply, it writes "selected" when I select two dates instead of "sélectionnés". Is there anything I did wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <div id="app">
          <v-app id="inspire">
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                <v-date-picker locale="fr"  v-model="dates" range></v-date-picker>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                <v-text-field v-model="dateRangeText" label="Date range" prepend-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly></v-text-field>
                model: {{ dates }}
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-app>
        </div>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: () => ({
        dates: ['2019-09-10', '2019-09-20'],
      }),
      computed: {
        dateRangeText () {
          return this.dates.join(' ~ ')
        },
      },
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<v-date-picker
              v-model="date"
              locale="fr"
              selectedItemsText="{0} sélectionnés"
>
```

Bye.